# Terminal edit command in a editor

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I am coming from the postgres world, and am not very new to UNIX.
My question is, if there is a way to invoke a editor from command line, and when I close the editor the output flows to the shell.
Something similar to `\e` command available in postgres, where I type in a query, edit it easily in a editor instead of in the repl, and then I quit the editor to see the output of what I typed in, along with the query.

Comment: I am sorry, but can I know which would be the right place to ask this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In bash you can <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> (two stroke combo) to send the shell's readline to your $EDITOR. On exit of the editor, the command is executed.

Zsh and other shells have similar functionality, that may need to be configured.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks a lot.. Sorry to the other folks, I guess my question wasn't conveyed properly.

Comment: There's also the `fc` command to edit an arbirary command from the shell edit history.

Comment: We did some experiments with GUI editors and `ctrl+x`, `ctrl+e` -- The editor needs to shutdown before bash runs the contents of the command buffer.  The MS VS Code editor didn't work so well, the buffer was empty.  Too slow Electron ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Kate has a console plugin which allows you to flush the text straight to the console

Read more here http://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/kate/

EDIT: even more here https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/548031-expert-tips-and-tricks-with-kate-and-konsole

Comment: Am not sure if your answer was even relevant!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to write a shell script that does more or less what you're talking about. The simplest version, I think, would be something like this.

```
$ cat test.sh
vi test.sql
psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 sandbox < test.sql | less
```

Comment: thanks.. but this is not what I was looking for, the right answer is given by `demure`